# iphone+string operation

Tags: iphone

i am having an string like bellow:

> J B Tower, Drive In, Ahmedabad,
>   &# 2327; &# 2369; &# 2332; &# 2352 ;&# 2366 ;&# 2340 ;
>   380054 (Kabir Restaurant),

Now i want to remove this --

> &# 2327 ;&# 2369 ;&# 2332 ;&# 2352 ;&# 2366 ;&# 2340 ;

i had used this operation:-

```
NSString *substring = nil;  
NSRange newlineRange = [lblAddress.text rangeOfString:@"&#"];   
if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) 
{   
substring = [TargetString substringFromIndex:newlineRange.location];        
//[substring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:substring withString:@""];        
TargetString=[TargetString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:substring withString:@""];
}
```

As a result i got the TargetString===>J B Tower, Drive In, Ahmedabad,
substring===>&# 2327 ;&# 2369 ;&# 2332 ;&# 2352 ;&# 2366 ;&# 2340 ;  380054 (Kabir Restaurant),

But i want the string as====>
J B Tower, Drive In, Ahmedabad,380054 (Kabir Restaurant),

Please help me.

Comment: Do you always know what will be the string you want to remove?

Comment: atulyy the problem is गुजरात is comming in the form of ==>&#2327;&#2369;&#2332;&#2352;&#2366;&#2340; way.So i always know that the character always start from "&#" and want to cut the upto the last semicolen.

Comment: Run it through an XML parser and extract the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *s =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"J B Tower, Drive In, Ahmedabad, &# 2327; &# 2369; &# 2332; &# 2352 ;&# 2366 ;&# 2340 ;380054 (Kabir Restaurant),"];

NSArray * split=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

int  tempIndex = (int)([[split objectAtIndex:3] rangeOfString:@";" options:NSBackwardsSearch].location);
NSString * str=[[split objectAtIndex:3] substringToIndex:tempIndex+1];

s=[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:str withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. NSString *substring = nil;
 NSRange newlineRange = [lblAddress.text rangeOfString:@", &#"];
 if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
  substring = [lblAddress.text substringFromIndex:newlineRange.location];
  range = [substring rangeOfString:@";" options:NSBackwardsSearch];  
  newString = [substring substringToIndex:range.location];  
  s= [lblAddress.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(newlineRange.location,range.location)]; 
  lblAddress.text = [lblAddress.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:s withString:@""];  
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use below function.

```
-(void)getFinalString:(NSString *)pstrMainString:(NSString *)pstrRemovedString{

NSString *strFinalString;

NSArray *arraySplitted = [pstrMainString componentsSeparatedByString:pstrRemovedString];
NSMutableArray *arrayFinalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: arraySplitted];

if([arrayFinalArray count]==1){
    strFinalString = [arrayFinalArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
else if([arrayFinalArray count]==2){
    strFinalString = [arrayFinalArray objectAtIndex:0];
    strFinalString = [strFinalString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [arrayFinalArray objectAtIndex:1]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", strFinalString);
}
```

Here, pstrMainString = "J B Tower, Drive In, Ahmedabad, गुजरात 380054 (Kabir Restaurant),"

And pstrRemovedString = "गुजरात"

It will display final string which you want.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the reply.But it was my mistak i had edited my question.Please check it.And even i tried ur solution but it doest not show the proper answer